# Assign Array elements to the matched pattern in order

Tags: shell, for-loop, sed

I have a xml having similar blocks throughout the file:

```
<name> test </name>
<marker>
<name> test </name>

<xyz> some txt </xyz>
<abc> something </abc>

<name>test</name>
<marker>
<name>test</name>
```

Now, i want to find "marker" and replace the line above and below the first marker with  test1 , 2nd marker with  test2  and so on

i tried:

```
array=( test1, test2); 
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++)); do;
sed -i '/<marker>/!b;n;c<name>'`echo ${array[$i]}`'<\/name>' filename;
done
```

The problem here is: it replaces all the values with test2 always.
but I want a sequential replacement as the 1st marker should have test1 above and below, the 2nd marker should have test2 above and below and so on.

Comment: It doesn't replace all the values with test2 *always*. It replaces every maker with test1 on the first iteration and then it replaces every marker with test2 on the second iteration. You need to add a mechanism to replace only one occurrence each time.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{x;s/^/1/;x};N;/\n<marker>/!{P;D};N;G;s/.*(\n.*\n).*\n(.*)/<name>test\2<\/name>\1<name>test\2<\/name>/;x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x' file
```

At the start of the file prime the counter with 1. The counter is held in the hold space and incremented after each substitution.

Make a window of two lines throughout the files length. If the second line in the window does not begins `<marker>`, print the first line and then delete it and repeat. Otherwise, append a third line and then append the counter from the hold space. Using pattern matching, substitute the first and third lines with required test.

Finally increment the counter, ready for the next match and print the last three lines that have been amended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find any easy way to do this with a one-line but a simple script can get it done:

```
matchcount=`grep '<marker>' -c test-input.txt`
i=1
while [[ $i -le $matchcount ]]
do
  line=`grep '<marker>' -m 1 -n test-input.txt | grep -o '^[0-9*]'`
  nextline=$((line+1))
  prevline=$((line-1))
  cmd1=`echo $prevline`'s/.*/<name>test'`echo $i`'<\/name>/'
  cmd2=`echo $line`'s/.*/REPLACED/'
  cmd3=`echo $nextline`'s/.*/<name>test'`echo $i`'<\/name>/'
  sed -i $cmd1 test-input.txt
  sed -i $cmd2 test-input.txt
  sed -i $cmd3 test-input.txt
  ((i = i + 1))
done
sed -i 's/REPLACED/<marker>/' test-input.txt
```

Explanation:

- Iterate as many times as `<marker>` appears in the file
- Find the first occurrence of `<marker>` with grep, save it's line number and the surrounding ones.
- For each line use a different sed command: replace name or replace marker ocurrence so it doesn't match again.
- Replace all REPLACED back to  once it's done

I'm sure it can be made in fewer lines but this is made to be simple to read. You're welcome to improve it if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do.
Operations are restricted to range 1,/marker/ and marker is replaced by another word, to avoid a second matching. A last sed at the end restores all marker values.

To simplify, replacement is done with multiline replacement string with quoted '\n'.

```
array=( test1 test2);
marker='<marker>'
processed='<markerprocessed>' # or whatever cannot happen in input
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++)); do
    replace='<name>'${array[$i]}'<\/name>\n'${processed}'\n<name>'${array[$i]}'<\/name>' # edit as required
    sed -i  -e '1,/${marker}/'s/${marker}/${replace}/  $file
done
sed -i s/${processed}/${marker}/ $file
```